# How to fetch Azure Databricks notebook run details

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Data Factory to run my databricks notebook, which creates job cluster at runtime, Now I want to know the status of those jobs, I mean whether they are Succeeded or Failed.
So may I know, how can I get that status of runs by using job id or run id.

Note: I have not created any jobs in my databricks workspace, I am running my notebooks using Azure Data Factory which created job cluster at the runtime and it runs that notebook on top of that cluster and then it terminated that cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json
import requests

gethooks= "https://" + databricks_instance_name + "/api/2.0/jobs/runs/list"     #add your databricks workspace instance name over here
headers={"Authorization": "Bearer ********************"}        # Add your databricks access token
response = requests.get(gethooks, headers=headers)

print(response.json())      # you will get all cluster and job related info over here in json format

# traversing through response.json
for element in response.json()['runs']:
    job_id = element['job_id']
    status = element['state']['result_state']
    job_path = element['task']['notebook_task']['notebook_path']
    job_name = job_path.split('/')
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go to the monitor page in Azure Data Factory. You'll be able to filter by runId here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#monitor-the-pipeline-run

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12134/possible-to-get-job-run-id-of-notebook-run-by-dbut.html

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson()
```